# Accessing session (client-session) from file in subfolder

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm coding an app with express 4.x and using mozilla's client-session module to create a session with secret etc. Now I created a new file called fun.js which is in a subdirectory of my app main directory. The question I have now is how can I access the data of this session in this fun.js?
I would be very glad about your help.

Cheers

Fabian

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to remember in a language like nodejs is that the code is not reloaded/reset on every request, the variables are persistent; which means that if you set variable a=10 then every user will see the same value.

Work more towards requests and think of every request as a user and add your variable in the request object and as the request object passes through different routes/plugins/middleware/views they all have access to the variable.

I usually do this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.isLogged =  req.isAuthenticated();
    if(req.isLogged){
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
}
    req.session = 'random session key'
    next();
});
```